# Model fields not updated

Tags: python, django, json, facebook, django-models

I wanted to add facebook feed to my website (only the first latest wall message). So I have created the model :

```
class FacebookFeed(models.Model):
    checked = models.DateTimeField(name="Time Checked", auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.TextField(name="Message", null=True)
    author = models.CharField(name="Author", max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField(name="Post time", null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = FacebookFeed.objects.all()
        if(queryset):
            return
        else:
            #super(FacebookFeed, self).save()
            super(FacebookFeed, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def check_time(self):
        if self.checked:
            now = datetime.utcnow()
            diff = now - self.checked
            if diff.seconds >= 3600:
                return True
        return False
```

I want to perform feed update only each full hour so that's what check_time method is for. Now the function being used in my view :

```
def getSocialFeed():
    #facebook
    fb = FacebookFeed.objects.all()
    created = False
    if not fb:
        logging.debug('not fb')
        f = FacebookFeed();
        f.save()
        created = True
    fb = FacebookFeed.objects.all()[0]

    if fb.check_time() or created:
        logging.debug('check time true')
        conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("graph.facebook.com")
        conn.request("GET", '/UserName/feed')
        r = conn.getresponse()
        jsonResult = r.read()
        json = simplejson.loads(jsonResult)
        json = json['data']

        notAuthor = False
        i = 0
        if json:
            logging.debug('json')
            while notAuthor is not True:
                logging.debug('while')
                if json[i]['from']['name'] == 'UserName':
                    logging.debug('result %s' % (json[i]['from']['name'] == 'UserName'))
                    logging.debug('message: %s' % json[i]['message'])
                    date = json[i]['created_time'].replace('T', ' ')
                    logging.debug('date: %s' % date)
                    date = date[0:-5]
                    logging.debug('date2: %s' % date)
                    logging.debug('fb: %s' % fb)
                    fb.message = json[i]['message']
                    fb.date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    fb.author = 'UserName'                    
                    try:
                        x = fb.save()
                        logging.debug('x: %s' % x)
                        notAuthor = True
                        logging.debug(fb.message)
                        logging.debug(notAuthor)
                    except Exception, e:
                        logging.debug('e: %s' % e)
                else:
                    i+=1

        f = FacebookFeed.objects.all()[0]
        logging.debug('msg: %s' % f.message)
```

I've got the json response parsed, extracted all the data I want but somehow my object is not saved corretcly. Any ideas why ?

This is the debug log :

```
2011-05-27 14:15:24,671 DEBUG not fb
2011-05-27 14:15:24,681 DEBUG check time true
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG json
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG while
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG result True
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG message: sometext
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG date: 2011-05-26 14:42:36+0000
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG date2: 2011-05-26 14:42:36
2011-05-27 14:15:26,607 DEBUG fb: FacebookFeed object
2011-05-27 14:15:26,608 DEBUG x: None
2011-05-27 14:15:26,608 DEBUG sometext
2011-05-27 14:15:26,608 DEBUG True
2011-05-27 14:15:26,608 DEBUG msg: None
```

Comment: In order to make your code a lot more manageable, you should have a look at [the get_or_create documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = FacebookFeed.objects.all()
        if(queryset):
            return
        else:
            #super(FacebookFeed, self).save()
            super(FacebookFeed, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

i think `if(queryset)`  is always `True` if it contains records or not, to check for empty queryset, use `queryset.count() == 0` instead

Comment: damn guess i messed up. Because my object won't be saved if it already exist. thanks.